# How does hidemyass find public proxies?

Tags: proxy

I don't know if superuser is the right place to ask this question but I'm gonna give it a shot. I've been always wondering how websites like hidemyass find public ip:port proxies and keep them fresh? There are many other websites that just scrape hidemyass and put the proxies on their website. But how does hidemyass do it? Do they check ports on a list of ips?

Update:

There are some tools out there like scrapebox that scans for proxies. But is that how hidemyass finds proxies?

Comment: Instead of just down voting, leave a comment please.

Comment: Somebody said in this question's review queue *This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.* which isn't much ehp but in the help center it says don't ask about websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,

Comment: I mentioned that I'm not sure if superuser is the best place to ask this question. Then where should I post it?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but based on my previous comment you could try posting it at [Web Applications Q&A](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), but it might not work in its present form because Web Applications Q&A is more about how to use a website rather than how that website is developed internally.

Answer (score 2):

They don't "find" them, they deploy the servers themselves.

The Free proxy is effectively promotion for them - when you want a better / faster / stronger level of protection then you upgrade.

(Although not specifically stated, it is [implied](https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy) here.) - specifically they say "Our free Proxy service...", along with a comparison of their services.